# changing php variable on "scroll"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php variable `$start1`, and I need to increase this variable by a value of '10' everytime the user reaches the bottom of the page. I read something about ajax but I don't know how to implement it.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

// increase $start1 by '10'
```

I tried storing the php-variable in a js-variable but somehow it did not work out. Would appreciate some help! Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying this value needs to persist from page to page?  That is, if the user reloads the page or navigates to a new page, should the value reset?

Comment: yes, if a user refreshes the page or goes to another, the variable should go back to the original value! :-)

Comment: So what do you need to do with this value in PHP?

Comment: it's supposed to be a $start variable for a mySql-query (as a limit parameter), as a part of infinite scrolling! Do you think this is the wrong way to go about this?

Comment: What my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to actually keep track of and increment `$start` in PHP.  What you really need is a `start` variable in javascript and an API for fetching the content.

It looks like you actually want to do something like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var start = 0;
    var loading = false;
    if( !loading && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() ) {
        start += 10;
        loading = true;
        $.ajax( {
            url: 'http://yourwebsite.com/yourapi.php?start='+start,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function( result ) {
                $('#content').append( result );
                loading = false;
            }
        } );
    }
});
```

Then you want to write an API in PHP that takes the `$start` value from the querystring ( `$_REQUEST['start']` in this case ) and echoes the appropriate content.

Make sense?